# iPad fires twice on click event

Tags: javascript, jquery, ipad

I have tried other examples with similar problems, but non have worked for me.

I think maybe because its a dynamically created area that the event is taking place in. everything in class `mapster_tootlip` and itself is dynamically created.

anyway here is a snip of the HTML

[image]

Here is some of my code

```
$( "body" ).on( "click touchstart", ".painTick_yes", function(evt) {
    evt.stopPropagation();
    evt.preventDefault();

    evt.stopImmediatePropagation();

    var full_id = $(this).attr('id');
    var id = full_id.replace("_yes", "");
    $("#"+id+"_no").removeClass("btn-success");
    $("#"+id+"_no").addClass("btn-default");
    $("#"+id+"_yes").removeClass("btn-default");
    $("#"+id+"_yes").addClass("btn-danger");
    $("#"+id + '_pain').val('true');

    alert(id+" - true");
    jointListClickEvent(id, true);

    $('#'+id+"_text").focus();
});
```

The alert fires twice, even when I dont have an alert if fires twice ( one answer link suggested it was only when a alert was present that it fired twice )

The earliest Static parent is `body`, so im wondering because it hase to bubble up so far, that it might be a cause.

Ive tried, like you can see, all combinations of `evt.stopPropagation();`, `evt.preventDefault();` and `evt.stopImmediatePropagation();`

I have tried to do it id checkboxes and buttons, but nothing seems to work.

Comment: `one answer link suggested it was only when a alert was present that it fired twice` that is nonsense. You're handling both a `click` and a `touchstart` event. The first thing I'd try is using `.on("click", ...)` instead.

Comment: wow. okay, I though it would be either and not all. thanks. that seems to have solved it. ( initiate FacePalm )